# VBA Find text & fill row with calculation

Tags: excel, vba

Please assist. I want a code to look through column B for text "Days Stock Cover". Once found, I need to insert a recurring formula 3 cells from the text (same row). This must loop right through the file until every row with Days Stock Cover has the  calculation. I don't know where to start.

I'm able to find the cell and to insert the calculation; but I don't know how to link it.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried (and read [ask]).

Comment: You could look up the `.FindNext` function, apply it to a range (e.g. column B) and take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim i as integer
i=1
do until cells(i,2) = "" '2 is equal to Column B, do as long as the column goes
    if cells(i,2).value = "Days Stock Cover" then
        Range("E"& i).Formula = "=SUM(B4:B9)" 'enter the desired column and formula
    end if
    i = i+1
loop
```